# is there a command line in ChromeOS which is equivilent to the terminal in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, chromebook, google-chrome-os

The terminal(penguin) in ChromeOS is just a VM which does not really seem to effect the chromeos it self. And then you got crosh which does not save things after you close it. So is there a full function terminal like the one in linux?

Comment: I'd guess if there were it would be pretty well documented. Besides these two, what other research have you done and what have you tried? Knowing what you're actually trying to accomplish, what you want the terminal FOR, may help us get you better, and more relevant, information. Because I'm guessing that, based on what you have shown already, the answer to this is going to be a simple "no".

Comment: ChromeOS GUI interface has too limited function for me, I need some thing like the terminal to access it's full performace.

Comment: Do you own this Chromebook, or is it loaned to you for work or school or some other purpose, and managed by someone else?

Comment: I do own the chromebook, is a personal one

Comment: https://chromeos.dev/en/productivity/terminal is penguin documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [enable **Developer Mode**](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/developer_mode.md) in order to save changes. Modern ChromeOS devices can be put into developer mode by pressing [specific keys](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/debug_buttons.md) while ChromeOS is booting.

From here you can log in as the root user `chronos`. Then start the command prompt through VT-2 by pressing: `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`→`, or through `crosh` (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`, then run the `shell` command).

The developer mode shell is basically just bash, complete with `sudo` commands. Read through the linked document for how to make the filesystem writable (to save changes), how to leave developer mode, usage examples, etc.:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/developer_mode.md

Comment: Thank you very much, I am already in developer mode. But where do you log in as chronos

Comment: @james.yi At the login prompt - By default, you can login as the chronos user with no password (take a look through the linked doc). And if it was helpful, please vote or mark as answered

Comment: I am under developer mode, what is the difrence between the crosh and VT2? Which one is more powerful

Comment: in v.117 they tooked away sudo su

Answer (score 0):

ChromeOS Shell, or ChroSH, IS the ChromeOS "terminal". ChromeOS is a locked down, limited function OS, and so it is normal and expected that the ChroSH is also limited in what it can do.

While you can install alternate terminal apps, such as the Linux Terminal, on ChromeOS, these are going to function within the limited rights assigned to apps on that system.

Comment: What limitation does chromeos shell have?